# Google Maps API v3 returning ZERO_RESULTS but Maps.Google.com showing fine

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

need some help with this one.

I'm using Google Maps API v3 to grab the latitude and longitude of human readable addresses stored in my database, then placing 1 marker on a Google Map canvas. Pretty straightforward.

The problem I'm experiencing is that some addresses are kicking back a status code of --> ZERO_RESULTS

If I type these same addresses into maps.google.com they will find that specific area and map it with a marker with an approximation.

Some of the addresses I have in my database are not specific, meaning they may not have a Postal Code and/or they may not have a City, but all have a Province/Region and Country. Also important to note is that none of them have a Street Address.

Some of the human readable addresses may have dashes (-), spaces ( ), apostrophes ('), and commas(,)

An example of an address that is kicking back ZERO_RESULTS is:

```
Soul-t'ukpyolsi, Korea, South
```

In that specific example, the Country has a comma and space in the name, and also the Region has an apostrophe and a dash.

Here is the Javascript code I'm using:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=MYKEY&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat; ?>,<?php echo $long; ?>);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

I'm using PHP to generate the full address path based on address elements stored in my database. Here is the code I'm using to generate the path and then issue the geolocator request:

Remember that City and Postal Code/Zip are optional elements

```
// Replace any spaces in vars
if (isset($gmaps_city)){
    $gmaps_city = str_replace(" ","+",$gmaps_city);
}
if (isset($gmaps_province)){
    $gmaps_province = str_replace(" ","+",$gmaps_province);
}
if (isset($gmaps_country)){
    $gmaps_country = str_replace(" ","+",$gmaps_country);
}
if (isset($gmaps_pcode)){
    $gmaps_pcode = str_replace(" ","+",$gmaps_pcode);
}

// If Postal Code and City
if (isset($gmaps_city) AND isset($gmaps_pcode)){ 
    $gmaps_path = $gmaps_city.",+".$gmaps_province.",+".$gmaps_country.",+".$gmaps_pcode."&sensor=false"; 

// If City but no Postal Code
} else if (isset($gmaps_city) AND !isset($gmaps_pcode)){ 
    $gmaps_path = $gmaps_city.",+".$gmaps_province.",+".$gmaps_country."&sensor=false"; 

// If Postal Code but no City
} else if (!isset($gmaps_city) AND isset($gmaps_pcode)){ 
    $gmaps_path = $gmaps_province.",+".$gmaps_country.",+".$gmaps_pcode."&sensor=false"; 

// Only Province and Country
} else { 
    $gmaps_path = $gmaps_province.",+".$gmaps_country."&sensor=false"; 
}

// Determine Lat and Long of Address
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$gmaps_path);

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

$status = $output->status;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think this address `Soul-t'ukpyolsi, Korea, South` works in Google Maps? Please provide a link to a good result (I get [Seoul](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Soul-t'ukpyolsi,+Korea,+South)).

Comment: Believe the source of the problem to be the misspelling, it should instead be --> Seoul-t'ukpyolsi,Korea,South ... Believe it works in Google Maps because going to Maps.Google.com and typing in "Soul-t'ukpyolsi, Korea, South" (incorrect spelling) does place a marker on Seoul. Just generating ZERO_RESULTS via JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example might be causing issues because of a misspelling. The following:
"Seoul-t'ukpyolsi, Korea, South"
Does not return ZERO_RESULTS.

The dashes and apostrophes should not cause problems based on your code. Please provide another example.

Comment: Same here: `Seoul-t'ukpyolsi,Korea,South` provide full JSON result.

Comment: Looks like the misspelling was the source of the problem. Thanks for the catch. Even still though, when typing "Soul-t'ukpyolsi, Korea, South" (with incorrect spelling) into Maps.Google.com it places a marker properly on Seoul. Is there any way I can replicate that same effect to provide JSON result for correct spelling? Rather than getting ZERO_RESULTS back from incorrect spelling.

Comment: I've asked the same thing but have yet to find a way that google offers to check this. A possible way to prevent this would be to check user input as they type or submit and check against ZERO_RESULTS and suggest there was a spelling error. However, it will most likely count against your query count and so would not be ideal.

Comment: Alternatively you check input against your own database and leverage the information you already have. Also, I would appreciate an arrow up for the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help Lothilius ... much appreciated. I've marked this as the accepted answer. Also, I tried to up arrow "mark as useful" but apparently I don't have enough "reputation" yet cuz I just joined stackoverflow. I'll come back and up arrow once I get enough "reputation" points.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the correct address each time, you could use the Places Autocomplete so the user can select a place from suggested addresses based on what they type in the search box:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete

You can also check out Geocoding best practices here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices